# Facebook oauth for accounts with managed page not switching (using Facebook as your page)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth, facebook-authentication

I have an application that uses facebook oauth and it is working fine. However, I am having problems when an account with a managed page is currently logged and is using Facebook as the page itself "use facebook as xxxx".

It gives the page and says:

xxxx would like to access your public profile and friend list.

Then as I click okay:

It goes to https://www.facebook.com/login/roadblock.php (no target_url)

Saying:

You are using Facebook as xxxx

To access this page, you'll need to switch from using Facebook as your page to using Facebook as yourself.

Then as I click continue..
It is not swithching.. It does not do anything and just goes to my facebook homepage (managed page).

Any solution for this rather than reauthentication?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue :( I haven't come across a solution.. except maybe to create a landing page on facebook canvas. This will prompt them to switch from "Page" to "Personal" before going through your application setup.